# Imagen al pasar mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Como hago para que al pasar el mouse por encima de una palabra aparezca una imagen debajo de ella.
Como lo que hace Wikipedia. como en esta imagen que al poner el mouse encima aparase una img y texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es el mismo truco que con los menus desplegables \\_(°-°)_/

Comment: sería recomendable que compartieras lo que has trabajado del código para ayudarte en función de lo que ya tienes y no estar adivinando cómo estás haciendo la estructura y los estilos.

Comment: .. Si no lo toco... no lo muestro... si lo toco... lo muestro.

Comment: Por el momento para no cargarla solo tengo un texto largo en <p> y algunas modificaciones en css para el tamaño del letra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías intentar lo siguiente amigo:

HTML:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <p>Pasa el mouse para desplegar la imagen</p>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
       <img src="img/imagen.jpg">
       <p>Cualquier texto aquí</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Lo ideal es no contestar cuando no se ha demostrado un poco de avance. Literalmente obtuve 3 soluciones inmediatas buscando en google. Por eso ves a 3 personas consultando lo mismo en comentarios.

Comment: ¿Qué se hace @Excorpion? ¿Elimino la respuesta?

Comment: No es necesario, el OP pudo ya haber copiado la solución. Lo mejor es dejarla y corregir a futuro.

Comment: De acuerdo. Gracias

Comment: Gracias Edgar